# Why are some python builtin "functions" actually types?

Tags: python

Many iterator "functions" in the `__builtin__` module are actually implemented as types, even although the documentation talks about them as being "functions". Take for instance `enumerate`. The documentation says that it is equivalent to:

```
def enumerate(sequence, start=0):
    n = start
    for elem in sequence:
        yield n, elem
        n += 1
```

Which is exactly as I would have implemented it, of course. However, I ran the following test with the previous definition, and got this:

```
>>> x = enumerate(range(10))
>>> x
<generator object enumerate at 0x01ED9F08>
```

Which is what I expect. However, when using the `__builtin__` version, I get this:

```
>>> x = enumerate(range(10))
>>> x
<enumerate object at 0x01EE9EE0>
```

From this I infer that it is defined as

```
class enumerate:
    def __init__(self, sequence, start=0):
        # ....

    def __iter__(self):
        # ...
```

Rather than in the *standard* form the documentation shows. Now I can understand how this works, and how it is equivalent to the *standard* form, what I want to know is what is the reason to do it this way. Is it more efficient this way? Does it has something to do with these functions being implemented in C (I don't know if they are, but I suspect so)?

I'm using Python 2.7.2, just in case the difference is important.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Is that a problem to you? Function and classes are just callable objects...

Comment: @JBernardo It's not a problem in almost all circumstances (and when it is, you should probably just fix the hack that breaks). But it's still interesting.

Comment: No, of course not. Its just an academic question. I want to know the rationale behind their implementation, when implementing generators is so easy. And maybe it will give me some insight into the question of: should I do it this way for my own generators?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Yes, it has to do with the fact that built-ins are generally implemented in C. Really often C code will introduce new types instead of plain functions, as in the case of `enumerate`.
Writing them in C provide finer control over them and often some performance improvements,
and since there is no real downside it's a natural choice.

Take into account that to write the equivalent of:

```
def enumerate(sequence, start=0):
    n = start
    for elem in sequence:
        yield n, elem
        n += 1
```

in C, i.e. *a new instance of a generator*, you should create a code object that contains the actual bytecode. This is not impossible, but is not so easier than writing a new type which simply implements `__iter__` and `__next__` calling the Python C-API, plus the other advantages of having a different type.

So, in the case of `enumerate` and `reversed` it's simply because it provides better performance, and it's more maintainable.

Other advantages include:

- You can add methods to the type(e.g. `chain.from_iterable`). This could be done even with functions, but you'd have to first define them and then manually set the attributes, which doesn't look so clean.
- You can us `isinstance` on the iterables. This could allow some optimizations(e.g if you know that `isinstance(iterable, itertools.repeat)`, then you may be able to optimize the code since you know which values will be yielded.

---

Edit: Just to clarify what I mean by:

> in C, i.e. a new instance of a generator, you should create a code
>   object that contains the actual bytecode.

Looking at `Objects/genobject.c` the only function to create a `PyGen_Type` instance is `PyGen_New` whose signature is:

```
PyObject *
PyGen_New(PyFrameObject *f)
```

Now, looking at `Objects/frameobject.c` we can see that to create a `PyFrameObject` you *must* call `PyFrame_New`, which has this signature:

```
PyFrameObject *
PyFrame_New(PyThreadState *tstate, PyCodeObject *code, PyObject *globals,
            PyObject *locals)
```

As you can see it *requires* a `PyCodeObject` instance. `PyCodeObject`s are how the python interpreter represents bytecode internally(e.g. a `PyCodeObject` can represent the bytecode of a function), so: **yes, to create a `PyGen_Type` instance from C you must manually create the bytecode**, and it's not so easy to create `PyCodeObject`s since `PyCode_New` has this signature:

```
PyCodeObject *
PyCode_New(int argcount, int kwonlyargcount,
           int nlocals, int stacksize, int flags,
           PyObject *code, PyObject *consts, PyObject *names,
           PyObject *varnames, PyObject *freevars, PyObject *cellvars,
           PyObject *filename, PyObject *name, int firstlineno,
           PyObject *lnotab)
```

Note how it contains arguments such as `firstlineno`, `filename` which are obviously meant to be obtained by python source and not from other C code. Obviously you can create it in C, but I'm not at all sure that it would require less characters than writing a simple new type.

Comment: Do you have to? A large number of functions are written in C, and I really really doubt one can't emulate generators in C. Whether it's pretty or useful is another question entirely ;-)

Comment: Why do functions written in C have to be new types?

Comment: @martineau I probably generalized too much. What I wanted to say is that creating a new generator in C means to manually create the bytecode for the function, which is an overkill and not so "confortable". Writing a new type with `__iter__` and `__next__` methods is pretty easy and provides more benefits.

Comment: @Bakuriu Writing a generator in C **does NOT** mean manually creating bytecode. Using the C API doesn't create bytecode, it's writing C code that calls specific functions and creates specific structs to interact with the python interpreter. This answer is incomplete, as it assumes using the C API is the same as implementing the corresponding protocol in python.

Comment: @forivall I update my answer explaining why you are *wrong*. By the way, I have never stated that C API creates bytecode, the `PyCodeObject` **does** contain it, and `PyGen_Type` **requires** it to be instantiated.

Comment: @Bakuriu Yes, that's what's necessary to create a `GeneratorType`. However, `enumerate` is not a generator, it is a completely disparate type that implements the C iterator protocol. (Sorry, I shouldn't have said generator **in my comment, I was wrong**). I'll add a code sample later tonight; it's much less verbose than creating a PyFrameObject, etc. So yes, **you're right** when it comes to generators, but _not when it comes to enumerate_, it's not a generator (No frames/bytecode necessary!). I'll be amending my answer likewise.

Comment: @forivall You probably skipped the beginning of my answer: "Really often C code will introduce new types instead of plain functions, **as in the case of enumerate**".

Comment: @Bakuriu And then, you go on to explain something completely unrelated: how it's done in python. Interesting and enlightening though, but it has nothing to do with the original question. (If you want to talk to me more, I'll be lurking on #python)

Comment: @forivall The OP mentioned the fact that it probably had to do with the fact that they are implemented in C. I showed why it's not a good idea to write in C `enumerate` as a function instead of implementing it as a new type, so it **is** related to the OP's doubts.

Comment: @Bakuriu Yup, you're showing them what's not happening I'm showing them what's actually happening. Please see my previous comment, or ping me in SO chat.

Comment: Yes, the easiest way to create a new type is to just implement a new type, instead of calling PyFrame_New. But why do you think you need to call PyFrame_New to implement a function in C?

Comment: @LennartRegebro Please point out where I stated that I have to call `PyFrame_New` to implement a function, so that I can clarify that part. **You must call `PyFrame_New` to create a `generator` instance which is what the OP asked**. That's the point I wanted to make. Sure you can create an `enumerate` function but if you want a function written in C such that `enumerate(X)` is a `generator` instance then, somewhere, you have to call `PyFrame_New`. If this is not so point out *how* you would do that in your answer(in a way that is simpler to defining a new type/using `PyFrame_New`).

Comment: I disagree that this is what the OP asked. Your answer is why enumerate is easier to implement as a class/type in C than a generator, but it doesn't answer the generic question that the OP actually asked.

Comment: @LennartRegebro I believe you did not read all my answer(or you didn't read it carefully enough). For example some points I made are: 1) A type is more maintanible 2) You can add methods to it (providing `chain` example) 3) You can use `isinstance` to see what kind of iterable is it. If you think I could express these points in a better way then I can edit my answer to highlight them, but *they are already there*.

Comment: Well, you write it like it's effects of implementing them in C, it could be clarified that this is not the case.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, they're implemented in C. They use the C API for iterators ([PEP 234](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0234/)), in which iterators are defined by creating new types that have the `tp_iternext` slot.

The functions that are created by the generator function syntax (`yield`) are 'magical' functions that return a special generator object. These are instances of `types.GeneratorType`, which you cannot manually create. If a different library that uses the C API defines its own iterator type, it won't be an instance of `GeneratorType`, but it'll still implement the C API iterator protocol.

Therefore, the `enumerate` type is a distinct type that is different from `GeneratorType`, and you can use it like any other type, with `isinstance` and such (although you shouldn't).

---

Unlike Bakuriu's answer, `enumerate` isn't a generator, so there's no bytecode/frames.

```
$ grep -i 'frame\|gen' Objects/enumobject.c
    PyObject_GenericGetAttr,        /* tp_getattro */
    PyType_GenericAlloc,            /* tp_alloc */
    PyObject_GenericGetAttr,        /* tp_getattro */
    PyType_GenericAlloc,            /* tp_alloc */
```

Instead, the way you create a new enumobject is with the function `enum_new`, whose signature doesn't use a frame

```
static PyObject *
enum_new(PyTypeObject *type, PyObject *args, PyObject *kwds)
```

This function is placed within the `tp_new` slot of the `PyEnum_Type` struct (of type `PyTypeObject`). Here, we also see that the `tp_iternext` slot is occupied by the `enum_next` function, which contains straightforward C code that gets the next item of the iterator it's enumerating over, and then returns a PyObject (a tuple).

Moving on, `PyEnum_Type` is then placed into the builtin module (`Python/bltinmodule.c`) with the name `enumerate`, so that it is publicly accessible.

No bytecode needed. Pure C. Much more efficient than any pure python or `generatortype` implementation.

Comment: I **never** stated that `enumerate` requires "bytecode" or frame objects. I stated that to create a new instance of `GeneratorType` requires that, and so *would* `enumerate` if it were implemented as a function returning a `GeneratorType` instance.

Comment: @Bakuriu And I accused you of saying such a thing. Your answer is devoted to defining a generator in C. But nobody does that, we define custom iterator types in C.

Comment: If I wanted to turn enumerate into a function in C, I would use `PyCFunction_New*` and make it return a custom object, say, a PyEnum_Type. Hooray for duck typing: we don't need to care that it's not an instance of 'GeneratorType'.

Comment: My answer is devoted to answering the question, which is: 1) *Why* `enumerate` is not a simple generator but a new type and 2) if it has to do with being written in C. The OP never asked *how* `enumerate` is actually implemented.

Comment: "The OP never asked how enumerate is actually implemented." Yup. "Why enumerate is not a simple generator but a new type" Nope. He asked why they're not "functions". I explained that generators are constructed by special functions that aren't manually created (they only make sense when written in python with a 'yield' function). And then you explained how to write a generator in C. How silly. So I explained how 'enumerate' _is_ written in C, and how it doesn't need to be generator.

Comment: +1. I wonder why this answer has so few +1 - it does more accurately answer the question, IMHO.

Comment: @glglgl Both this question and Bakirus question answer the question "Why is enumerate it's own type, instead of a generator". That's a valid question, but it's not the question actually asked.

Answer (score 1):

The `enumerate` call needs to return an iterator. An iterator is an object with a specific API. The easiest way of implementing a class with a specific API is generally to, well, implementing it as a class.

The reason it says "type" instead of "class" is Python 2 specific, as builtin classes was called "types" in Python 2, as a rest of Python having both types and classes before Python 2.2. In Python 2.3 classes and types was unified. And in Python 3 it therefore it says class:

```
>>> enumerate
<class 'enumerate'>
```

This makes it clearer that your question **"Why is some builtins types instead of functions"** has very little to do with them being implemented in C. They are types/classes because that was the best way to implement the functionality. It's that easy.

Now if we instead interpret your question as **"Why is `enumerate` a type/class instead of a generator"** (which is a very different question), then the answer is also naturally different. The answer there is that generators are Python shortcuts for creating iterators from Python functions. They are not intended for use from C. They are also less useful for making generators out of functions than out of class methods, as if you want to create an iterator object out of a class method you need to also pass in the object context, but with a function you don't need this. So there it's mostly the benefit that you have less "scaffolding" code.

Comment: I fail to see how the python3/python2 difference has *anything* to do with the OP question(since he only mentioned python2.7). Also "They are types/classes because that was the best way to implement the functionality" is kind of obvious, otherwise it would mean that python devs like to waste time doing things in the hard way without any advantage. The OP question is more specific.

Comment: @Bakuriu: The point is that Python 2 calling it "types" has led people to think this has something to do with them being implemented in C, as evident from the two other answers. This is **wrong**. It has nothing to do with them being implemented in C. This is evident from Python 3, where they are no longer types, but classes.

Comment: @Bakuriu I clarified the question.

Comment: I believe the OP was *well* aware of that. In fact note the "From this I infer that it is defined as

`class enumerate: ...`". No C code here. Also the OP himself admits he does *not* know whether their are implemented in C or not. He is asking: "why is is `enumerate(sequence)` an instance of `enumerate` and not an instance of `generator`? May it be related to the fact that, *maybe* it is implemented in C?". At least this is what *I* read in the question when I answered and I believe being implemented in C **is** an issue, as I've explained.

Comment: @Bakuriu What the OP is well aware of is less relevant than answering the question the OP actually posts, as SO is supposed to be generically useful.

Comment: @LennartRegebro We're answering the questions posted at the bottom of the body of the question, rather than in the title. Perhaps the title question is a little misleading or possibly ambiguous -- to disambiguate, you could replace it with "Why are some python builtin “functions” actually of type "type" instead of type "function"?" or "instead of type "class"", or the specific, "Why is the builtin `enumerate` of type "type" instead of (...) and return "enumerate" objects rather than "generator" objects?" --- (<- edit: that's your answer)
---
Really, we should move this discussion over to meta.